# comparing keys in one array with another

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Ruby Newbie here. I have been banging my head up against a wall for the better part of two hours now due to an assignment that I have. I am to create a method has two arguments - a Hash and Array of keys derived from that hash's keys. The method should return true if the Array has all of the keys in the hash, and false if it does not. I have to make sure every key in the hash argument is also contained in the array_of_keys argument. The method should return true if all of the elements in the array_of_keys array are within the set of keys in the hash argument, without regard to a specific order. The writers of the assignment suggested using the .sort method to do this.

This is what I have so far, however I am having an issue figuring out how to sort both arrays in order to compare.

```
def do_i_have?(hash, array_of_keys)
  array_of_keys = []
  hash.each do |key, value|
    array_of_keys << key
  end
  hash.keys == array_of_keys
end
```

I have also tried, but no luck.

```
def do_i_have?(hash, array_of_keys)
  array_of_keys = []
  hash.each do |key, value|
    array_of_keys << key
  end
  hash.keys.sort == array_of_keys.sort
end
```

What is the correct syntax in order to sort and compare these two arrays?

Thanks guys!

When I use the second method, Rspec tells me:

```
 do_i_have? returns true if all keys are in the hash
 do_i_have? returns true if all keys are in the hash, regardless of order
```

but,

```
do_i_have? DOES NOT return false if it doesn't have any of the keys
do_i_have? DOES NOT return false if one or more of the keys isn't in the hash
do_i_have? DOES NOT return false if the hash has a different number of keys than the array
```

Rspec:

```
describe "do_i_have?" do
  it "returns false if it doesn't have any of the keys" do
    h = { name: "Computer", cost: "$1,000" }
    keys = [:age, :bio]

    expect( do_i_have?(h, keys) ).to eq(false)
  end
  it "returns false if one or more of the keys isn't in the hash" do
    h = { name: "Computer", cost: "$1,000" }
    keys = [:name, :bio, :cost]

    expect( do_i_have?(h, keys) ).to eq(false)
  end
  it "returns false if the hash has a different number of keys than the array" do
    h = { name: "Computer", cost: "$1,000" }
    keys = [:name]

    expect( do_i_have?(h, keys) ).to eq(false)
  end  
  it "returns true if all keys are in the hash" do
    h = { name: "Computer", cost: "$1,000", uuid: "1234" }
    keys = [:name, :cost, :uuid]

    expect( do_i_have?(h, keys) ).to eq(true)
  end
  it "returns true if all keys are in the hash, regardless of order" do
    h = { name: "Computer", cost: "$1,000", uuid: "1234" }
    keys = [:name, :uuid, :cost]

    expect( do_i_have?(h, keys) ).to eq(true)
  end  
end
```

Comment: Is your method supposed to be given the array of keys, or is it supposed to generate and verify the array (as you are showing)? Also, you can get the array of keys from a hash simply with, `hash.keys`. You should browse the class documentation for Ruby Hash and Ruby Array for the available methods. Finally, an array is *ordered* so order matters (which is why your first attempt won't generally work). I ran your second method and it came back "true" so it appears to work.

Comment: The method is supposed to generate the array from the keys in the hash then verify that the array has all of the keys in the hash. And yes I am aware that hash.keys will give you an array of the hash's keys in a specific order. However I need to sort both the array_of_keys and hash.keys so they can be compared and I can be given either true or false results. However my second method did not pass the tests that were required to pass the assignment.

Comment: Can you edit your submission to include your test suite as well?

Comment: You can still use `hash.keys.sort` if you need to sort them. I still am not seeing why you need the `hash.each` loop. If you want to use a loop, you could use `hash.each_key do |key|` since you aren't using the value. But neither method guarantees the order of keys since Ruby doesn't maintain the keys of a hash as an ordered collection.

Comment: @vikram7 I am currently taking a course so all of the exercises are done in browser, but I have added what my tests are telling me to the original submission.

Answer (score 1):

This feels like cheating, but why not...

```
$ cat foo.rb

def do_i_have?(hash, array_of_keys)
  hash.size == (hash.keys & array_of_keys).size
end

hash = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

puts do_i_have?(hash, [:a, :b, :c])
puts do_i_have?(hash, [:c, :a, :b])
puts do_i_have?(hash, [:a, :b])
```

And when run:

```
$ ruby foo.rb
true
true
false
```

No need to sort them... `hash.keys & array_of_keys` will contain all fields that are common to both arrays (excluding duplicates). So if it is the same size as the keys in the hash, then they have to be the same set, right?

Comment: This almost satisfies my assignment requirements but my tests are saying that `do_i_have? DOES NOT return false if one or more of the keys isn't in the hash`

Comment: Ah, I missed that requirement. I'll leave it to you to tweak to handle that condition :)

Answer (score 1):

The class [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html) has a method that returns an array of a hash's keys. If you go through `Hash`'s instance methods at the link in the previous sentence, you will find that method. It is easier than what you have (which is correct, incidentally):

```
array_of_keys = []
hash.each do |key, value|
  array_of_keys << key
end
```

Your main problem is comparing two arrays, not for equality, but for having the same values, but not necessarily in the same order. That's because:

```
([1,2] == [2,1]) #=> false
```

There are several ways you can determine if two arrays, `a` and `b` have the same elements. Here are three:

- sort `a` and `b` and then see if the two sorted arrays are equal. You need to use the method [Array#sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html) for that.
- see if every element in `a` is in `b` and every element in `b` is in `a` (hint: consider the method [Array#-](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-2D)).
- convert `a` and `b` to [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html)s and determine if the two sets are equal. (To use methods of the class `Set` you need `require 'set'`. To convert an array `a` to a set you can use `s = Set.new(a)`.

Answer (score 1):

An array of a hash's keys can simply be generated by `hash.keys`. If you sort that array and compare it against a sorted version of the array you're passing into that method, you should be good:

```
def do_i_have?(hash, array)
  hash.keys.sort == array.sort
end
```

Comment: What about duplicates in the array? No idea if that's good or bad for OP, but might be an issue.